# Do 11D SUGRA fields exist at the fundamental level of M theory?

Tags: string-theory, supergravity

The M branes in M theory are a configuration of the fields of 11D sugra, but sugra is a low energy limit of M theory. So do these fields exist at the fundamental level of the theory, and if not, what are m branes?
Also, how does the M5 brane get its magnetic charge? An object gets its electric charge by the motion around the circular dimension. Does the same apply for magnetic charge?

Comment: of course m-branes exist in M-theory, otherwise they wouldn't exist in 11D SUGRA. M5 is magnetic dual of M2, that's why it has magnetic charge.

Comment: @Kosm what I’m asking is if the fields in 11D SUGRA exist in the fundamental level of M theory. If they don’t, how would M branes arise?

Comment: they do exist in M-theory in some form, but the exact picture is not known, because complete non-perturbative M-theory is not known.

Comment: @Kosm This then means that M branes are not fundamental, and it's really the SUGRA fields that are fundamental. Correct?

Comment: M-branes ARE solution to sugra

Comment: and therefore M-branes are sugra field configurations (solitonic). They are as fundamental as branes in string theories

Comment: @Kosm Thanks. So going back to the M5 brane, they just intrinsically have a magnetic charge, and do not arise due to dynamics (like electric charge in kaluza klein)? what is the force carrier particle for the magnetic charge?

Comment: yes, just like magnetic monopoles. Kaluza-Klein charge arises  after compactification

Comment: @Kosm what is the force carrier particle for the magnetic charge? Also on a side note, do you study string theory for your PhD?

Comment: magnetic force is part of electromagnetism, so force carriers are photons, or gauge vector bosons in general. In string theory those correspond to open string modes

Comment: for off-topic matters or long discussions you can create a chat room and send me an invitation

Comment: @Kosm unfortunately I can't create a chat room because I don't have enough of a reputation. Can you create a chat room and then add me?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/82022/m-room